# Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview

Hear is just the idea what i am thinking to implement this,

I want to implement book like pages, for this i want to take UITableView and rotated-90 degree and its cell by 90 degree, and now  i want to subclass UITableViewCell, now within this tableview cell it is possible to add UITableview  so that user can scroll vertically to see the contents and user can also scroll horizontally to go to next cell of rotated tableview. 
It is just i am thinking, is there any better way to implement this.

Comment: How would you support reordering across different table views?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

yes it is possible, I added the UITableVIew within the UITableView cell 
.. :)

no need to add tableview cell in xib file - just subclass the UITableviewCell and use the code below, a cell will be created programatically.

```
//in your main TableView 

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

 - (void)dealloc 
{
 [_aTV release];
 [super dealloc];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
  return 1;
 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  return 3;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomCell *cell = [self.aTV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
   if(cell == nil)
   {
     cell = [[[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]autorelease];
   }

  cell.dataAraay = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"subMenu->1",@"subMenu->2",@"subMenu->3",@"subMenu->4",@"subMenu->5", nil];
return  cell;
}

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 150;
}


//in your custom tableview cell 
//  .m file
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell 
@synthesize dataAraay; //array to hold submenu data

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
   self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
   UITableView *subMenuTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain]; //create tableview a

  subMenuTableView.tag = 100;
  subMenuTableView.delegate = self;
  subMenuTableView.dataSource = self;
  [self addSubview:subMenuTableView]; // add it cell
  [subMenuTableView release]; // for without ARC
  }
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 -(void)layoutSubviews
 {
   [super layoutSubviews];
   UITableView *subMenuTableView =(UITableView *) [self viewWithTag:100];
   subMenuTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.3, self.bounds.size.width-5,    self.bounds.size.height-5);//set the frames for tableview

}

  //manage datasource and  delegate for submenu tableview
 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
     return 1;
  }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
   return dataAraay.count;
 }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"]autorelease];
   }
  cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataAraay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;

}

@end
```

**Swift version**
Create a `single view project` add `tableview` inside `storyboard` and set up its `datasource` and `delegate`

Paste code below to `ViewController.swift`

```
  import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 3;
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 1;
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      var cell:CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as?  CustomCell
      if cell == nil {
         cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
      }
      cell?.dataArr = ["subMenu->1","subMenu->2","subMenu->3","subMenu->4","subMenu->5"]
      return cell! 
   }

   func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 150.0
   }
}
```

create a new file `CustomCell.swift` which is the subclass of `UITableViewCell` and `do not select with xib` this file is without `.xib` file `table` and its `cell` will be created programatically as in `objective-c code`.

Paste code below to `CustomCell.swift`

```
  import UIKit

  class CustomCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

  var dataArr:[String] = []
  var subMenuTable:UITableView?
  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style: style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
      setUpTable()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      setUpTable()
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
      setUpTable()
  }

  func setUpTable(){
      subMenuTable = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style:UITableViewStyle.Plain)
      subMenuTable?.delegate = self
      subMenuTable?.dataSource = self
      self.addSubview(subMenuTable!)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      subMenuTable?.frame = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.3, self.bounds.size.width-5, self.bounds.size.height-5)
  }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
      super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
      // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return dataArr.count
  }

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      return 1
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellID")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = dataArr[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Shan how to delegate the table view inside cell for storyboards?

Comment: Does CustomCell need to implement `UITableViewDataSource` in order for its `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get called?

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky, yes for the tableview inside the parent cell need to confirm's to delegate and datasource , in the above code i am doing it programatically by  `subMenuTableView.delegate = self` and
 `subMenuTableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: @SurgePedroza add swift version check it

Comment: @EICaptain one possible option would be using delegate to view controller from custom cell.

Comment: is inside tableview scrollable?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov :yes they are scrollable

Comment: I had tried by seeing your answer I had placed table view in separate section in which I am loading the data with api but the problem is in first section whenever the radio button enables at that time the third section needs to be showed but while showing I need to call the api how can I call the api and load the data can you help me how to do this ? @ShankarBS

Comment: How about handling tapped cell to be handled from main view

Comment: @Osa did mean handling the tapped cell action in view controller

Comment: @ShankarBS I meant what if i want to handle the tap action in main view controller class, and not this class

Comment: @Osa you can define a custom delegate from custom cell to view controller to handle tap action

Comment: `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
      setUpTable()
  }` setUpTable() should be removed here cause it will never be executed.

Comment: is it possible to add a custom cell inside a table view which is already a subview of custom table view cell?

Comment: @RamcharanReddy yes it is possible to add custom cell.

Comment: When you passed your model instance to your view(cell here) you are not using MVC anymore. Also note if your model is of pass by value type, your edits wont reflect back when you copied..!

Comment: `required init?` caused the fatal error for me. Try using `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}`

Answer (score 11):

Better way: use a `UIPageViewController` for your left/right page scrolling.  Each page can contain a table view.

Answer (score 6):

Although rob's Idea is better but yes it is possible. Check how:

Take 2 table view, give them tag  1, 2, let's call these kTagBaseTableView, kTagInnerTableView. Now below is the blue print, how to deat with two table view, with delegate and data source attached to single view controller.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{              // Default is 1 if not implemented
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case kTagBaseTableView:
            return baseSectionCount;
            break;
        case kTagInnerTableView:
            return innerSectionCount;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case kTagBaseTableView:
            return [baseDataSource count];
            break;
        case kTagInnerTableView:
            return [innerDataSource count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case kTagBaseTableView:{
            static NSString* baseIdentifier = @"baseTableViewCell";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:genderIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:genderIdentifier];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(titleKey, nil);
            return cell;

        }
            break;
        case kTagInnerTableView:{
            static NSString* innerIdentifier = @"innerTableViewCell";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:genderIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:genderIdentifier];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(titleKey, nil);
            return cell;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{    // fixed font style. use custom view (UILabel) if you want something different
    switch (tableView.tag) {
        case kTagBaseTableView:
            break;
        case kTagInnerTableView:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}

//TABLE VIEW DELEGATE
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    switch (tableView.tag) {
      case kTagBaseTableView:{}
          break;
      case kTagInnerTableView:{
      }
          break;
      default:
          break;
   ￼}
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If the content of the inner table depends on the outer table, how do you know which row in the outer table is selected when you process case statements for the kTagInnerTableView?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass for tableView and override the intrinsicContentSize. [I have answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674808/is-it-possible-to-implement-tableview-inside-tableview-cell-in-swift-3/52251422#52251422)

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "API.h"
#import "Parsing.pch"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "HomeCollectionViewCellForSubCat.h"
#import "CollectionViewTableViewCell.h"
#import "NewsTableViewCell.h"
#import "CategoryTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeCollectionViewCellForSubCat.h"
#import "WebviewController.h"
#import "TopFreeAppsCollectionViewTableViewCell.h"
#import "TopSitesCollectionViewTableViewCell.h"
#import "TrandingVideoCollectionViewTableViewCell.h"
#import "SportsTableViewCell.h"
#import "JokesTableViewCell.h"
@interface HomeViewController ()
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
    NSMutableArray *Details;
    NSIndexPath *IndexPath;
    CollectionVIewTableViewCell *TrafficCell;
    NewsTableViewCell *NewsCell;
    CategoryTableViewCell *CategoryCell;
    TopFreeAppsCollectionViewTableViewCell *TopAppsCell;
    TopSitesCollectionViewTableViewCell *TopSitesCell;
    TrandingVideoCollectionViewTableViewCell *TrendingVideosCell;
    SportsTableViewCell *SportsCell;
    JokesTableViewCell *JokesCell;
}
@end
NSString *More;
NSMutableArray *news;

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];


}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"Traffic" ])
    {
        if(!TrafficCell)
        {
            TrafficCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CollectionVIewTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            TrafficCell.Traffic = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [TrafficCell.collectionView reloadData];
            return TrafficCell;
        }
        return TrafficCell;
    }
    else if([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"News"])
    {
        if(!NewsCell)
        {
            NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            cell.News = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [cell.NewsTableView reloadData];
            return cell;
        }
        return NewsCell;

    }
    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"TopApps"])
    {
        if(!TopAppsCell)
        {
            TopAppsCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TopFreeAppsCollectionViewTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            TopAppsCell.TopApps = [[dict valueForKey:@"detail"]valueForKey:@"small_banner"];
            [TopAppsCell.TopAppsCollectionView reloadData];
            return TopAppsCell;
        }
        return TopAppsCell;
    }

    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"TopSites"])
    {
        if(!TopSitesCell)
        {
            TopSitesCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TopSitesCollectionViewTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            TopSitesCell.TopSites = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [TopSitesCell.TopSitesCollectionView reloadData];
            return TopSitesCell;
        }
        return TopSitesCell;
    }

    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"Category"])
    {
        if(!CategoryCell)
        {
            CategoryCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            CategoryCell.Category = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [CategoryCell.CategorycollectionView reloadData];
            return CategoryCell;
        }
        return CategoryCell;
    }

    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"TrendingVideos"])
    {
        if(!TrendingVideosCell)
        {
            TrendingVideosCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrandingVideoCollectionViewTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            TrendingVideosCell.TrendingVideos = [[dict valueForKey:@"detail"]valueForKey:@"small_banner"];
            [TrendingVideosCell.VideosCollectionView reloadData];
            return TrendingVideosCell;
        }
        return TrendingVideosCell;
    }

    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"Sports"])
    {
        if(!SportsCell)
        {
            SportsCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SportsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            SportsCell.Sports = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [SportsCell.SportsTableView reloadData];
            return SportsCell;
        }
        return SportsCell;
    }

    else if ([[dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqual:@"Jokes"])
    {
        if(!JokesCell)
        {
            JokesCell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JokesTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSDictionary *dict=dataArray[indexPath.row];
            JokesCell.Jokes = [dict valueForKey:@"detail"];
            [JokesCell.JokesTableView reloadData];
            return JokesCell;
        }
        return JokesCell;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return nil;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *dict = dataArray[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Traffic" ])
    {
        //Find your collectionView in cell
        //Tap on Traffic cells
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"News"])
    {
        //Tap on News cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Category"])
    {
        //Tap on Category cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TopApps"])
    {
        //Tap on TopApps cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TopSites"])
    {
        //Tap on TopSites cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TrendingVideos"])
    {
        //Tap on Trending cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Sports"])
    {
        //Tap on Sports cells

    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Jokes"])
    {
        //Tap on Jokes cells
    }
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = dataArray[indexPath.row];
    if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Traffic" ])
    {
        return 155;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"News"])
    {
        return 300;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Category"])
    {
        return 120;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TopApps"])
    {
        return 180;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TopSites"])
    {
        return 240;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"TrendingVideos"])
    {
        return 270;
    }
    else if([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Sports"])
    {
        return 310;
    }
    else if ([dict[@"type"] isEqual:@"Jokes"])
    {
        return 280;
    }
    return 200;
}
```