# How to Add Dynamic Table View in Static Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Static Table View in my storyboard and it have 3 cells in it.
First 2 Cell have some labels and i wish to add a dynamic table view in 3rd Cell .

What will be the probable process to achieve this , how can i provide datasource to my table view in the 3rd cell?

[image]

Comment: you take two tableview and in table view check tableview with your tableview like in number of section put if(tableView==tableview1)return 30else return 40 like this and adjust it as per requirement

Comment: what if i like to have a static table view a parent view and a small list i want to use dynamic table view then what should be the approach !!

Comment: where is your problem when user click on third cell show your dynamic table.But you are asking for how to use data source use the if condition and check inttableview with tbaleView

Comment: see this question, but pretty complex,though u can implement it,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: It will be very kind of you can provide me the working source code to download the project so that i can have a real better idea .

Comment: it is a custom cell u can create a cell as u are creating the custom cell  and return it from your tableview simple ... u want me to post that code too .. ?

Comment: being greedy , i wish if i get a code for the same :)