# Can we add UITableView into Custom UITableViewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I want to add one `UITableView` on which there are two types of Custom `UITableViewCell`.
One of Cell should contain `UITableView` with other custom Cells H. This is how my code for of the `UITableViewCell` looks, on which I added another `UITableView`.

```
#import "MainDetailsCell.h"
#import "SubCell.h"

static NSString * const     SubCellIdentifier =  @"SubCell";

@implementation MainDetailsCell


- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
    [_DetailsTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:SubCellIdentifier bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:SubCellIdentifier];

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

#pragma mark  -tableview Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *retCell;

    SubCell *cell = [_DetailsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LocationDetailsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    retCell=cell;

    [retCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return retCell;
}



@end
```

Comment: You should consider redesigning your structure. Using a UITableView inside another is not a good design. Alternatively, you could push another UITableViewController on the tap of the cell with the intended contents.

Comment: Yes you can. I have done this many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a `UITableView` on `UITableViewCell` -

For more info related to the same refer below link-

[Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)