# Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

How do I add `UITableView` in `UITableViewCell`, the `UITableView` in each `UITableViewCell` is with different data?

How to show this json in UITableView:

```
"DiviDeta": [
                          {
                            "Id": 12453,
                            "Nombre": "BATIDO",
                            "Precio": 1800,
                            "Sabores": [
                              {
                                "Id": 564,
                                "Nombre": "FEIJOA"
                              },
                              {
                                "Id": 565,
                                "Nombre": "GUANABANA"
                              },
                              {
                                "Id": 562,
                                "Nombre": "LULO"
                              },
                              {
                                "Id": 561,
                                "Nombre": "MANGO"
                              },
                              {
                                "Id": 566,
                                "Nombre": "MARACUYA"
                              },
                              {
                                "Id": 563,
                                "Nombre": "MORA"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
```

Comment: Yes it just, just use add tableview as a subView into cell.

Comment: an example would help me much

Comment: may be you dont need to add..just display another tableView on tapping the cell..but remeber to set the frame correctly

Comment: The same thing i also have to ask. if i am working with expanded tableview the i can create a another tableview on tapping the cell.@anishparajuli

Comment: the same question is on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939952

Comment: Maybe this link is  helpful for you @Andres Marin  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYJRQyAtQYg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it before but not in swift, in Objective C.

Below are steps to add TableView on TableviewCell:

1. Make TableView Cell class with xib.

`@interface CollapsableCell_iPhone : UITableViewCell` `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`

2. Add View on content view.on that view add tableview and set delegates to tableview cell class.

[image]

3. Implement delegate method inside tableview cell class.
4. Use this cell in Your Tableview as many time as required.

   ```
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollapsableCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];

   CollapsableCell_iPhone *cell = (CollapsableCell_iPhone *)[nib lastObject];
   ```

Comment: this is in Objective-C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell but no en Swift