# Tableview within tableview swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I need to have a view which has a `UITableView` and the **main** `UITableView` has a cell that has another tableview.
I have added the view on storyboard and implemented the delegate and datasource methods in a single viewcontroller.
But the tableview methods are not getting called for the inner tableview since i have set inner tableview delegate and datasource like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

    switch tableView.tag {
    case 1:
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let pendingReportsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PendingReportsCell") as! PendingReportsTableViewCell
            pendingReportsCell.taxYearTableView.delegate = self
            pendingReportsCell.taxYearTableView.dataSource = self
            taxTableView = pendingReportsCell.taxYearTableView
            taxTableView?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EarliestMonthTaxYearCell")
            tableView.tag = (taxTableView?.tag)!
            taxTableView?.reloadData()
 }
```

Please tell me an alternate to do this.

Comment: Why you need table view within table view?

Comment: you want to create menu ? with sub menu option

Comment: The UI Design is such that I need another tableview within another. No subviews are there. Just a tableview with 2 sections. The first section again having two sections and data within it.

Comment: @Roshni can you be more specific what is the requirement.What is that you are trying to design?

Comment: I cant share the design here. but a brief idea about what I want to do. I have a tableview with two sections: Pending and Completed Reports. The Pending Reports again has two sections for Current and Previous years with years inside cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065920/adding-uitableview-inside-uitableviewcell look this @Roshni

Comment: ok will check it. Thanks @Himanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the delegate and datasource in your custom cell class as below:-

```
       class PendingReportsCell: UITableViewCell {
         // set the delegate & datasource of taxYearTableView in the init or  
         // awakefromnib or storyboard. 
         // I have set it in storyboard and it works for me. 
         // Implement the datasource and delegate methods of taxYearTableView in this class.
         }
```

When taxTableView?.reloadData() is called it will invoke the above delegate and datasource methods