# How Pre Expanded UITableview which is again having UITableview in UITableCell in IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multi-level

I want two level list which is multi level UITableView. meaning A Tableview in IB, and having one prototype dynamic cell.

That cell is again having UITableView with its cell.

I have searched a lot... got Expanding header section. But I want pre expanded and never collapsed multi level UITableview.

Any link for ios 8, created using IB interface builder?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working for you about having a table view in a table view cell? Have you considered using a collection view instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell

from above link tired  @rptwsthi answer. where 2 tags of 2 tableviews are maintained, also 2 datas are maintained in that answer.

I have completed same idea in android by using ExpandableListview... 
Thats why I am searching for same in IOS

Comment: In android I successfully completed upto 3 level list using below:

http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html


And in IOS I want up to 2 level. but struggling. I don't want Expandable Section header. but already expandable list under list item.

Comment: I have added answer which I have found and integrated in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and achieved pre expanded UITableview by IOS 8, IOS 9

[HVTableView](https://github.com/innovian/HVTableView)

[image]