# How to create UITableview inside a UITableviewCell like Submenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to create tableview inside a `tableviewcell`like submenu.Right now i am using `SWRevealviewController` to open a `sidemenu` on Single ViewController screenshot below.

[image]

Right now i am using custom tableviewcell in in tableview.my question is how to create tableview inside one cell. For Example `Home->submenu1,submenu2` ,`TaskManagement->submenu1,submenu2`.

Any suggestions are most welcome Thanks

Comment: for sub menu you can do with a single table with section as `Home`, and rows for that section as `submenu1, submenu2`

Comment: Or u can insert custom row that look like sub menu (increase padding to left, smaller,...)

Comment: use sections to do this.or else if you want to use it try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell