# Swift Table within a Table

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Hello im a newbie and swift so kindly bear with me, is it possible to create a table in which its cell contains another group of table?

e.g.when a cell is clicked, it will expand and display another table.

Comment: do you mean accordion view?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: thanks @shan! @Smi yeah accordion view.