# How to create a custom tableview within another custom tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to integrate embedded table views where that the `UITableViewCell` of the parent `UITableView` contains another custom Table View. I am able to populate the other content of the parent table view cell(e.g. the label and an image view.). However, the child `UITableView` doesn't get populated with it's content and remains blank. 
This is the code from the main `UIViewController` that is the "parent" of the parent `UITableView`:

```
//table view delegate function
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return completedOrders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "completedOrdersCell", for: indexPath) as! CompletedOrdersTableViewCell
        let currentOrder = completedOrders[indexPath.row]
        cell.orderDate.text = dateToString(date: currentOrder.date)
        cell.orderTime.text = dateToTimeToString(date: currentOrder.date)
        cell.totalAmountPaid.text = "R\(String(format: "%.2f", currentOrder.totalCost))"
        cell.driverProfile.image = currentOrder.driverProfile
        cell.driverName.text = currentOrder.driverName
        cell.restaurantLocation.text = currentOrder.restaurantLocation
        cell.dropOffAddress.text = currentOrder.dropOffAddress
        cell.mealsJSON = currentOrder.mealsJSON
        cell.deliveryFee.text = "R\(currentOrder.deliveryFee)"
        cell.tip.text = "R\(String(format: "%.2f", Double(currentOrder.driverTip)))"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        completedOrderTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
```

Here is my code in the parent TableViewCell:

```
    @IBOutlet var mealsTableView: UITableView!
    var mealsJSON = ""

    struct Meal{
        var quantity = Int()
        var name = ""
        var price = Double()
    }
    var meals = [Meal]()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mealCell", for: indexPath) as! completedMealTableViewCell
        let currentMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
        cell.quantity.text = "\(currentMeal.quantity)"
        cell.name.text = currentMeal.name
        cell.amount.text = "R\(String(format: "%.2f", currentMeal.price))"
        return cell
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        mealsTableView.delegate = self
        mealsTableView.dataSource = self
        print(mealsJSON)
        jsonToMeal()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func jsonToMeal(){
        //set meals to data
        let mealJSONData = mealsJSON.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let readableJSON = JSON(data: mealJSONData!)
        //extract array from JSON
        for item in readableJSON["meals"].arrayValue{
            var newMeal = Meal()
            newMeal.quantity = item["mealQuantity"].intValue
            print(newMeal.quantity)
            newMeal.name = item["mealName"].stringValue
            print(newMeal.name)
            newMeal.price = item["mealPrice"].doubleValue
            print(newMeal.price)
            meals.append(newMeal)
        }
        mealsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Here is the code of the child `UITableViewCell`:

```
class completedMealTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var quantity: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var name: MarqueeLabel!
    @IBOutlet var amount: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the value of `meals.count` when you return it?

Comment: to answer your question we need also the code for the embedded TableView

Comment: i dont see any TableView inside the cell(from your current code)

Comment: without knowing your exact code from embedded TableView: in `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt)` normally you need to update the datasource of the embedded TableView and reload it with `reloadData()`

Comment: I have added the additional code from the viewController, parent tableViewCell & chill TableVewCell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: I accidentally din't include my tableView outlet when I copied from code. I have added it in now

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe that it's a better idea if you separate the code, one file for you tableView and one for you tableViewCell. Then, in your tableViewCell implement the`UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. Also, create the outlet for this tableView.

```
//
//  NewTableViewCell.swift
//  JustATest
//
//  Created by Alisson Enz Rossi on 1/11/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 com.Cotival.justATest. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class NewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
extension NewTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)

        //...

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

Also, create an array that you can fill this tableView, same as you did in your parent controller, and don't forget to change `numberOfRowsInSection` to count the number of items in your array. It should work.