# Adding table view with cells on the cells of another tableviewcells in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I hava a TableView on a Viewcontroller.On the tableview cells of that Tableview I want to add another tableview with table viewcells on it.Is it ppossible to achieve this in ios?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18820977/2164705) as he explains with details what you should do.

What you can also do is work with section/rows without adding more UITableView.

The first thing that comes to mind is to create a new tableView inside cellForRowAtIndexPath and give it a tag that corresponds to the row of the main TableView.

In case you have multiple sections, you can also add section to it like this `section * 1000 + row`

And in each cellForRowAtIndexPath you check if theres any tableView with the tag, if there is, just recall it

Comment: Yes,I have tried this one but not able to get the cells withincells.I have copied the whole code but the delegates of cells inside cells are not being called.

Comment: you want one dynamic tableView for every cell, or should one different tableView for each cell?

Comment: I want one dynamic tableView for every cell.

Comment: Updated answer above