# Is it possible to implement tableview inside tableview cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble with putting a tableview inside a uitableview cell. right now I am going to implement the comments and reply. and reply should be inside which you are going to comments. 
so I am going to implement comments of post in tableview cell, inside it reply of all that comments in other tableview cell.
Any suggestion or other way to implement these scenario!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell?rq=1).

Comment: While it's possible, it's generally not a good idea. Apple suggests you avoid nesting scrollable elements, because then they have to fight over which one received a given scroll gesture, and it's not a good user experience. This goes for a tableView inside a tableView, scrollView inside collectionView, et cetera. I would suggest emulating what many social media apps do, which is show 1 or 2 of the nested replies in a stack view with a tappable action to go to a different screen to view them all.

Comment: How did you solved this?

Answer (score 13):

[This Question is duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell/52247846?noredirect=1#comment91446479_52247846) 
Answer in Swift

**First Approach:**

1. Create a subclass for child tableView and override intrinsicContentSize.

   ```
        class MyOwnTableView: UITableView {
       override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
           self.layoutIfNeeded()
           return self.contentSize
       }

       override var contentSize: CGSize {
           didSet{
               self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
           }
       }

       override func reloadData() {
           super.reloadData()
           self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
       }
   }
   ```
2. In Interface builder change the class of your child tableView to MyOwnTableView (subclass of UITableView).
3. Set automatic row height for both the parent and child table view.

   ```
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   ```

**Second Approach:**
       1. Create a height constraint with any value for child tableView and conect an IBOutlet that sets the child tableView height.
2. Set the height constraint's constant to tableView.contentSize.height

```
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible however not a recommended way to implement. If you want to show replies below to each post along with the comment I would recommend you to implement through sections. Each section should have three types of cell as mentioned below:

- PostCellView
- ReplyCellView
- CommentCellView

In this case number of section would be number of posts and total number of rows for each section would be 1(Post) + N(where N is total number of replies) + 1(Comment).

With this approach you can add/remove replies through animation that Apple provides which is easy to implement.

I hope this will help you, please feel free to ask if you have any concerns.