# Can we add tableview to cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to customize my tableview. I want to add another tableview in cell. Can we add tableview in cell of another tableview?

Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Of course you can. What is your problem ? Share your code.

Comment: @Pipiks I don't know to how to add tableview in cell. I try to find with other tutorials but don't have any solution. If you know so tutorial link, can you share me? I just know how to add collection view in cell of tableview

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a `UITableView` into another `UITableView`'s cell, but due to potential issues with the embedded `UIScrollView`s it is not recommended.

If you feel like you need a table in a table, first consider if it is not possible to achieve the desired behavior by using sections and cells in the sections (a section in a table might represent the top `tableView`'s cell, and cells in the given section would represent the embedded `tableView`'s cells).

Comment: Here is my design for my app. Please spend about 1 minute to look on it. Can you give me what view that I can use? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y9Xgzuw5XV9aUnJDHv5TGn6uUlKPSFMh

Comment: I would start with `UITableView`, for topmost items I would probably use horizontal `UICollectionView`.. for the rest of the design, I would try to use section (and section headers) to create sections (Sport, Toys, etc.) and simple cells (unless those should be horizontally scrollable - then again, `UICollectionView`)

Comment: Nosal, Thank you. I will try

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with adding a UITableView into a a UITableViewCell, since both of them are `UIView`s its simply would be translated to adding a subview to a view...

However, keep in mind to consider the following issues:

1- From a user experience perspective, that would be a vertical scroll view inside another vertical scroll view (are you ok with that?).

2- For each cell -in the main container table view-, you would need to handle the table view delegates/datasources. For understanding the logic of how this could be done, you might want to check:

- [Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell).
- [Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/): although it is about adding a UICollectionView inside the cell, it helps to gain the logic of how to achieve such a task.

Comment: Here is my design for my app. Please spend about 1 minute to look on it. Can you give me what view that I can use? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y9Xgzuw5XV9aUnJDHv5TGn6uUlKPSFMh

Comment: @ChhengRavy for me, you should add a `UITableView`, inside their cells add a `UICollectionView` (As I mentioned, check "Putting a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell in Swift").

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try to follow your advice