# Is it possible to achieve expandable table header view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have implemented table view with expandable section i.e. the section user choose will have number of items for that particular category. For closed section there will be 0 items.

Now for better UI purpose, I want to achieve following type of table view which has expandable header view? In this image, we can see that section looks like a group with items it contains with rounded corners and border. As per default `UITableView`, this behavior is not possible. Still if any one has implemented, please give some advise whether it is feasible or not.

[image]

Comment: can't you achieve that with sections and rows ?

Comment: Rows always start after section. In my case, section's background is expanding. For example, see the difference between 'Brand' and 'Learning skills' header view UI.

Comment: so what i willl do in this case to have table inside table

Comment: In that case, how to define height of a table view?

Comment: outer or inner ? you have 2 data sets right

Comment: Yes... if I take table view inside cell, how height will be calculated??

Comment: height will be calculated on the basis of number of rows

Comment: why you needs height ? it all works on Automatic dimensions

Comment: If I take table view inside cell, and inner table view has 20 rows, how outer cell’s height will be increased automatically to contain those 20 rows rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214113/discussion-between-nspratik-and-jawadali).

Comment: using a tableview in a tableview cell is generally not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct WrapperObject {
    var header : HeaderObject
    var listObject : [ObjectDetail]
}

struct HeaderObject {
    var id : String
    var isOpen : Bool
}

struct ObjectDetail {
    var id : String
    var detailInfo : String
}
```

In your VC or datasource. Create : 
`private var internalData : [WrapperObject]`

After set data, in the delegate of UITableView

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            // TODO : Custom your own view
            // have a callback to set property isOpen =  true or false to the internalData.
            return UIView()
        }
    }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return internalData.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if internalData[section].header.isOpen {
                return internalData[section].listObject.count
            } else {
                return 0
            }

        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            return UITableViewCell() // TODO: custom your own cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i understand your question. I just create an example model for your tableView to adapt. Ok, i have updated much more detail.

Comment: That is right but in my case, UI is only issue. Look at image in question where header view id different when it is open. It contains all rows like grouping which is totally different than achieving simple expand and collapse.

Comment: So your problems is the border of every section or the UI of the session header. You mean the + or the - icon ?

Comment: Border of section. Look at `Learning Skills`. The header view behave like a parent view of all rows.

Comment: OK, i see, sorry for misunderstanding. In this case, if learning skill is really a header, I think you need to create a tableview inside that header. If learning skill does not behave like header (always top) look like that cell contains a mini tableview

Comment: something likes this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell/52247846?noredirect=1#comment91446479_52247846

Comment: Yes, but table view inside table view cell is not a good idea I think. We should avoid doing the same.